# Why is my array not working as intended?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I have been unable to submit my assignment because of one final discrepancy in my code. I've spent several hours trying to resolve it.

My code takes 20 test answers that can either be 'A', 'B', 'C', or 'D', and then tells you whether you passed (>=15 correct) or failed, how many you got right, and how many you got wrong. Afterwards, it tells you the question numbers of the ones you got wrong.

However, only the first few numbers are actually recorded to the array I am using, and the last 5 are not (it is always the last 5, regardless of how many you got wrong).  What's strange is, I'm using a `for` loop to read the values INTO the array, so there should not be discrepancies. If there was, it would most likely give me an `arrayIndexOutOfBoundsExeption`.

Here's the code, there is a comment for the method with the problem (starts at line 81):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ch7 {
    private static char[] correctAns = {
         'B', 'D', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'A', 
         'C', 'D', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'D', 'C', 
         'C', 'B', 'D', 'A'};

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean pass;
        char[] answers = new char[20];

        for(int x = 0; x < answers.length; x++) {

            do {
                System.out.printf("Enter your answer for question %d:",
                                  x + 1);
                answers[x] = kb.next().charAt(0);
            }
            while(answers[x] != 'A' && answers[x] != 'B' &&
                  answers[x] != 'C' && answers[x] != 'D' && 
                  answers[x] != 'a' && answers[x] != 'b' && 
                  answers[x] != 'c' && answers[x] != 'd');
        }

        for(int x = 0; x < answers.length; x++) {
            answers[x] = Character.toUpperCase(answers[x]);
        }

        pass = passed(answers);
        if(pass == true)
            System.out.println("You Passed!");
        else
            System.out.println("You did not pass.");

        System.out.printf("You got %d answers correct out of 20.\n",
                          totalCorrect(answers));

        System.out.printf("You answered %d questions incorrectly.\n",
                          totalIncorrect(answers));

        int[] qMissed = questionsMissed(answers);

        if(qMissed.length != 0) {
            System.out.print("You got questions ");
            for(int x = 0; x < qMissed.length; x++) {

                if(x == qMissed.length - 1)
                    System.out.printf("and #%d ", qMissed[x]);
                else
                    System.out.printf("#%d, ", qMissed[x]);
            }
            System.out.println("wrong.");
        }
    }

    public static boolean passed(char[] ans) {
        int correct = 0;
        int incorrect = 0;
        for(int x = 0; x < ans.length; x++) {
            if(ans[x] == correctAns[x]) {
                correct++;
            }
            else
                incorrect++;
        }
        return correct > incorrect ? true: false;
    }

    public static int totalCorrect(char[] ans) {
        int correct = 0;
        for(int x = 0; x < ans.length; x++) {
            if(ans[x] == correctAns[x]) {
                correct++;
            }
        }
            return correct;
    }

    public static int totalIncorrect(char[] ans) {
        int incorrect = 0;
        for(int x = 0; x < ans.length; x++) {
            if(ans[x] != correctAns[x]) {
                incorrect++;
            }
        }
        return incorrect;
    }

    // problem somewhere in this method
    public static int[] questionsMissed(char[] ans) { 
        int nMissed = totalIncorrect(ans);
        int[] missedQuestions = new int[nMissed];
        int i = 0;
        for(int x = 0; x < totalIncorrect(ans); x++) {
            if(ans[x] != correctAns[x]) {
                    missedQuestions[i] = x + 1;
                    i++;
            }
        }
        return missedQuestions;
    }
}
```

Comment: Any reason you are not running your code step-by-step under debugger?

Comment: Why is the loop based on `totalIncorrect`?

Comment: Any reason why you're just pasting a whole code with an error on the 81st line?

Comment: @PM77-1 I do not know how to use Eclipse's debugger.

Comment: @GalAbra I thought that the entirety of the code was necessary to understand what the holy hay the method does. I could have posted just the method, but you wouldn't have had any idea what the method did or what other methods it called.

Comment: If you don't know how to use debugger, add `System.out.println(//someVariable//)` after suspicious behaving of `someVariable`...

Comment: Hint: the error is in this line: `for(int x = 0; x < totalIncorrect(ans); x++) {`.   Think about it.  If you don't see the problem ... think some more.

Comment: @StephenC If you're referring to the `totalIncorrect` method call, that's not it, using several other things doesn't work either. `missedQuestions.length` and `nQuestions` do nothing different. I'm trying to think of other errors in that line, but don't see any possibilities... Why would an incorrect value in an array be due to an error in a `for` loop header? it has the correct length for all the test sets I used.

Comment: The totalIncorrect **call** is the problem.  Think some more.  Think about the value that it returns.  Is that the right value to use **for what you are doing there**?  (You might also want to read this: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: The `passed()` method is wrong too, I think.  Look at the description in your text at what qualifies for a pass, then look at what the method returns.

Comment: @markspace Whoops. I posted an earlier version of the code, I had resolved that in later versions.

Comment: @StephenC Are you talking about the call in line 85? That is to save me writing a `for` loop to determine the exact number of questions that are wrong. I had written the `for` loop in previous versions, but they caused the same problem, so I used the `totalincorrect` call as an attempt to see if that loop was more precise. After comparing the results of the two, which were the exact same, I decided to leave the call there.

Comment: @StephenC I have now officially read and tried all of the techniques in that blog post. Talking to a rubber duck made me feel quite silly, but I can see how that would be useful.

Comment: No.  I am talking specifically about the line that I quoted in my comment.  See above.   And forget about your previous attempts.  They are irrelevant.  The only relevant thing is what the code does NOW.

Comment: Let me spell it out.  You are not checking all of the answers.  You are only checking from answer 0 to answer "number of incorrect" - 1.  There are more answers than that.

Comment: @StephenC I feel stupid now. Next time I talk to a rubber duck, I will go expression by expression, not statement by statement. Thank you for your time helping me with this!

Comment: The duck is patient ....

Comment: No need to feel stupid. That is how you learn. For quicker debugging initialize `char[] answers = new char[] {'C', 'D', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'D',.......}` instead of using scanner.

Answer (score 0):

Well there is a simple mistake...you can figure it out yourself for why it should be like this...

HINT: check the condition in for-loop

```
    public static int[] questionsMissed(char[] ans) { 
        int nMissed = totalIncorrect(ans);
        int[] missedQuestions = new int[nMissed];
        int i = 0;
        for(int x = 0; x <ans.length; x++) {
            if(ans[x] != correctAns[x]) {
                    missedQuestions[i] = x + 1;
                    i++;
            }
        }
        return missedQuestions;
    }
```